# Most recent distinct record from a joined MySQL table

Tags: mysql, distinct

I have two tables, one of a list of competition results, and one with ELO ratings (based on previous competitions).
Fetching the list of competitors for an arbitrary competition is trivial enough, but I also need to get the most recent rating value for them.

score:

```
id | eventid | competitorid | position
1    1         1              1
2    1         2              2
3    1         3              3
4    2         2              1
5    2         3              2
6    3         1              1
7    3         3              2
8    3         2              3
```

rating:

```
id | competitorid | rating
1    1              1600
2    2              1500
3    3              1500
4    2              1600
5    3              1590
```

Expected output for a query against score.eventid = 3 would be

```
id | competitorid | position | rating
6    1              1          1600
7    3              2          1590
8    2              3          1600
```

At the moment my code looks like:

```
SELECT score.scoreID, score.competitorID, score.position,
rating.id, rating.rating
FROM score, rating
WHERE score.competitorid = rating.competitorid
AND score.eventid = 3
ORDER BY score.position
```

which gives an output of

```
id | competitorid | position | rating.id | rating
6    1              1          1          1600
7    3              2          2          1500
7    3              2          4          1590
8    2              3          3          1500
8    2              3          5          1600
```

basically it's showing the data from the score table for that correct event, but giving me a row for every rating available against that competitorID unfortunately I have no idea where to build in the DISTINCT statement or how to limit it to the most recent result.

MySQL noob, and managed DISTINCT statements, but not with joins. Unfortunately most previous questions seemed to deal with getting distinct results from a single table, which is not quite what I'm after. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get the rating is with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT s.scoreID, s.eventID, s.competitorID, s.position,
       (select r.rating
        from rating r
        where s.competitorID = r.competitorID
        order by r.id desc
        limit 1
       ) as rating
FROM score s
WHERE s.eventID = 3
ORDER BY s.position;
```

I'm not sure what `ratingprid` is, so this only includes the rating.

Comment: Thankyou very much, answer accepted - for future readers, ratingprid was a heading out of my actual database - I cleaned up the headers for readability in the sample data here (and stripped out a few columns not relevant to this query) and missed that one. Amended the question to correct it.